# QTP sometimes recognizes objects

Tags: qtp

I've been getting some strange behavior from QTP recently. Every now and then it can correctly identify an item during a Run, but other times I'll get an error message saying it cannot find that item, or it will actually identify another item instead. Has this happened to anyone before? I'm not sure if this is a QTP problem or something to do with the site I'm testing (my guess is the latter, it seems the culprit has to be when I'm interacting with WebElements). Could it also be a memory problem, such as I've used up too much memory that QTP can't store additional data?

Comment: Usually happens when too many similar items are in memory and the objects in your OR doesn't have enough unique properties to differentiate them.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't blessed by the QTP gods, and am really only going by the index value for each object since that's basically the only property I'm given (besides its html tag). It just seems like the index values change everytime I perform a run causing it to fail.

I've also tried descriptive programming it all, but it's the same thing. I'm about tempted to just automating it using the x and y coordinates even though that's not the best approach.

Comment: Disable smart identification. Also provide the object properties.

Comment: Get the developers to give everything an unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

if index of links are getting changed every time, use descriptive programming with Location instead to index.

index represents the occurrence of object in source code and location represent the occurrence of object in application gui.

So if gui is not changing and index of object is changing dynamically, you can use Location.

This will solve your problem.